# transposing multiple columns in bash

Tags: bash, perl

demilited file like this

```
Input1 file1:45764
Input1 file1:878755
Input1 file1: 899787
Input2 file1: 45676
Input2 file1:769678
Input2 file1: 6454764
```

and I wish to convert them into

```
Input1 file1:45764, file1:878755, file1: 899787 
Input2 file1:45676, file1:769678, file1: 6454764
```

Any guess? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{b[$1]=b[$1] $2$3"  "}END{for (i in b) print i,b[i]}' inputFile
```

will produce output as

```
Input1 file1:45764  file1:878755  file1:899787  
Input2 file1:45676  file1:769678  file1:6454764
```

what it does?

`{b[$1]=b[$1] $2$3"  "}` creates an array `b` appends the second and third column(since there was some spaces between`file` and `value` in your example).`$2$3`  into the array. The array is an associative array indexed by the `Inputx` where `x` is `1,2...`

that is

```
b['Input1'] = 'file1:45764  file1:878755  file1:899787'
```

`END` block is excecuted at end of input file, `input`,

`for (i in b) print i,b[i]}` prints the content of `b` array

Comment: You forgot the commas... :)

Answer (score 0):

And if you want those commas in the output, try

```awk
awk '{if(b[$1])b[$1] = b[$1]", "; b[$1] = b[$1] $2 $3}; END{for(i in b)print i, b[i]}'
```

or the slightly terser

```
awk '{b[$1]=b[$1](b[$1]?", ":"")$2$3}END{for(i in b)print i,b[i]}'
```

**output**

```
Input1 file1:45764, file1:878755, file1:899787
Input2 file1:45676, file1:769678, file1:6454764
```